# Orthogonal functions definition

Tags: orthogonality, signal-processing

I know the condition for two functions to be orthogonal. It is  $\int_{a}^{b}f_1(x)f_2(x)dx=0$. Also, on YouTube and websites this kind of formula is used, no other.

I read from my book Signals and Systems by HSU 1st edition in solved example a slightly different definition. I would like some help to better understand the definition. It uses a complex number and some other extra items that perplex it,makes it more generic(?) and it gets me confused. What for all the extra stuff in the definition? Why not use a simple definition as in 1st paragraph?

Here it is:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f_m(x)f^*_k(x)dx = \begin{align}\begin{cases}a & m \neq k  \\0      
 & m = k\end{cases} \end{align}$$

where $f^*_k(x)$ is a complex function. Also, $a \neq 0 $.

Comment: I presume you mean $\int_{a}^{b}f_1(x)f_2(x)\,dx$

Comment: The latter definition is appropriate for complex-valued functions, where $*$ denotes complex conjugation.

Comment: they are just complex conjugating the second function. This is standard for complex-valued stuff. For example, you want $1 = ||i||^2 = <i,i>$, so you can't have $<i,i> = ii$ but rather $<i,i> = i\overline{i}$.

Comment: i fixed my mistake in the integral

Comment: The second definition refers to a *set* of orthogonal functions $\{f_1(x), f_2(x),..., f_m(x),...\}$. It states that any two (distinct) functions of this set are orthogonal and each function is of energy $a$